# Accessing system tables using ArcObjects?

Tags: arcobjects, enterprise-geodatabase

I have a case to get the *maximum of year value* from the table schema in **GeoDatabase**.

**More detail:** I have a table named `SUPPLYMASTER` it contains the columns like `Supply2000, Supply2001, Supply2002, Supply2003, ... up to Supply2015` and it can be extended in future.

I can write the logic in simple SQL with the system tables as:

```
SELECT MAX(REPLACE([name], 'Supply', '')) AS [MaxYear] 
FROM sys.columns 
WHERE object_id = object_id('SUPPLYMASTER') AND [name] LIKE 'Supply%'
```

It filters the column names starting with `Supply` from the `SUPPLYMASTER` table, the **replace** will remove the `Supply` text from the filtered column names and **Max** will return the maximum number from the filtered values. So I will get the result as `2015`.

I tried the same in ArcObjects, but when trying to access the system table, it throws error.

I tried to access the system table like the below:

Config settings as:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="Database" value="DatabaseName"/>
    <add key="Server" value="ServerName"/>
    <add key="UserName" value="UserName"/>
    <add key="Password" value="Password"/>
    <add key="Version" value="DBO.DEFAULT"/>
</appSettings>
```

OpenTable code as:

```
IPropertySet connectionProperties = new PropertySetClass();
propertySet.SetProperty("Database", System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Database"]);
propertySet.SetProperty("INSTANCE", "sde:sqlserver:" + System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Server"]);
propertySet.SetProperty("USER", System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UserName"]);
propertySet.SetProperty("PASSWORD", System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Password"]);
propertySet.SetProperty("VERSION", System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Version"]);

Type factoryType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("esriDataSourcesGDB.SdeWorkspaceFactory");
IWorkspaceFactory workspaceFactory = (IWorkspaceFactory)Activator.CreateInstance(factoryType);
IWorkspace workspace = workspaceFactory.Open(connectionProperties, 0);

IFeatureWorkspace featureWorkspace = (IFeatureWorkspace)workspace;

ITable sysTable = featureWorkspace.OpenTable("sys.columns");

IQueryFilter sysTableFilter = new QueryFilterClass();
sysTableFilter.SubFields = "name";
sysTableFilter.WhereClause = "object_id = object_id('SUPPLYMASTER') AND [name] LIKE 'Supply%'";

ICursor cursor = sysTable.Search(sysTableFilter, true);
IRow row = null;

while ((row = cursor.NextRow()) != null)
{
  // .... data processing
}
```

It throws the error in the line `ITable sysTable = featureWorkspace.OpenTable("sys.columns");`

> DBMS table not found

How can I access the system tables using ArcObjects?

**Note:** I tried with `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` also, it throws the same error.

Comment: What was the workspacefactory? Are you accessing a database or a Geodatabase? Edit your code to show how you created featureworkspace.

Comment: @Hornbydd: Details added.

Comment: I'm not particularly familiar with SQL environment but you say you have a table called SUPPLYMASTER but your Arcobjects code is trying to open a table called "sys.objects"?

Comment: @Hornbydd: Requirement is I want to get the all column names of the `SupplyMaster` table and using those column names, to do some string operations. So trying to get the column names by the `sys.objects` table, since `sys.objects` contains the details of all table in the database.

Comment: Have you tried accessing the table with a database name prefix? I suspect you'll need to use a prepareSQL on the raw table because the table contains an unsupported type (OpenTable is only valid on feature classes).

Comment: @Vince: I tried with database name as prefix, but no luck.

Comment: Right. Then its not possible to access the system table column(s) through ArcObjects' OpenTable request (unsupported type(s)).  The connection object supports a generic SQL request. Use that instead (you may need to cast the results)

Comment: `IWorkspace.executeSQL` http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//002500000mrv000000

Comment: @Vince: `IWorkspace.executeSQL` describes in the link _The statement can be any DDL or DML statement but can not return any result sets._ It can affect the database and not return any data.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to ask Esri why, but it is not possible to access any `sys` tables directly using SE_table_describe, which means that any interface which accesses the system view piecemeal will fail.  The underlying ArcSDE functions can create a stream accessing the `sys.columns` view, and it's possible to generate a Query Layer on `sys.columns`, but `IFeatureWorkspace.OpenTable` cannot work on `sys` views.

You therefore have four options:

1. Fold the system view query into a valid SELECT statement as a subquery, e.g.

   SELECT name = (SELECT name FROM sys.columns WHERE ... ) FROM ...
2. Create a view which manifests a query on the system view, then use `OpenTable` on that
3. Create a Query Layer to implement your query
4. Use an ODBC connection to access the system view(s) in a SQL prepare.